# javascript looped linkedlist

Tags: javascript, linked-list

what is wrong with this code? I want to make something similar to looped linkedlist.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function LinkedText(text, nextLinkedText) {
            this.text = text;
            this.next = nextLinkedText;
            this.AsNext= function() {
                this.text = this.next.text;
                this.next = this.next.next;
                return this;
            }
        }

        var first = new LinkedText('first')
        var last = new LinkedText('last', first);
        first.next = last;

        alert(first.text); //show 'firts'
        alert(first.AsNext().text); //show 'last'
        alert(first.AsNext().text); //show 'last' not 'first' why?
        alert(first.AsNext().text); //show 'last'
        alert(first.AsNext().text); //show 'last' not 'first' why?
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite GetNext:

```
this.GetNext = function() {
    return this.next;
}
```

It makes no sense to re-assign *this.text* in GetNext when all you want is to get the linked node and access it's *text*.

You can use it like this:

```
var i = 0            // avoid infinite loop below
var maxruns = 10;    // avoid infinite loop below

var node = first;
while(node){
    doSomethingWithNode(node);
    node = node.GetNext();

    // avoid an infinite loop
    i++;
    if (i > maxruns) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1973846 No. You are always returning *this*, and not the *next* instance. And this style of programming is widely regarded as bad practice, as it violates the principle of referential transparency http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science\) . How are you gonna know in which position in the linked list you are at the moment? if after some calls to GetNext you want to have the original next element after first, it will be gone!

Comment: Thx. Now I understand my mistake. After reaching the end of defined structure I go back to my first object with is current object because I re-assigned it.